# Restore synchronized files/folders from Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

Is there a way to download every file I have uploaded to ubuntu one in one single download?

I have recently had a major hard drive crash and I would like to restore all my synchronized files on Ubuntu One on my new hard drive. The only way I found to do so is to download each files individually. Since I have many files (100s), I was wondering if there was a way to download every files/folders in my ubuntu one directory (on the server) in one single download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is sign into Ubuntu One in your new install of Ubuntu. This will start the syncing process to your new installation.

The files may take a little time to appear in the Ubuntu One folder, but they will eventually appear. There are ways you can check the syncing progress too from the indicator.

This also works for any other computer you might have too, say if you want to sync files between two machines.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

Is there any possibility that the synchronizing process will delete the files on the Ubuntu One server because it can not find the original files on my hard drive?

Comment: No, because deletion of files only occurs if you actually delete files, not if the files go missing.

Comment: Thanks again for the quick answer. I did so and I get an error saying:

"ROOT_MISMATCH: local and server roots are different"

Is it because local directories, especially the subfolders, are not the same as on the remote directories? Or is it something else I did wrong?

Comment: Nervermind, I have solved this issue by un/re-installing Unbuntu One by following these simple steps:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+faq/778

Comment: FWIW, ROOT_MISMATCH means you have Ubuntu One metadata (located in ~/.local/share/ubuntuone) for one Ubuntu One account and you're logged in with a different Ubuntu One account. I'll create an FAQ for this since it does tend to happen more often than I originally thought.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for files not in the Ubuntu One folder?