# Restore from Ubuntu One

Tags: restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore synchronized files/folders from Ubuntu One](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17621/restore-synchronized-files-folders-from-ubuntu-one)

One of these days I´m going to reïnstall Ubuntu 12.04 completely from scratch.
How can I then get my syncronized files back on my PC ? Is there a restore option ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just log back into Ubuntu One on your new installation and it will automaticly sync the files you have synced before if you do so chose.